# Seems like by uiimage encoding is altered before POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm currently working on sending uiimages to my server to be stored on the server. So I get an image from the user gallery and then encode it using Base64 and then send it to my server. However all the images I sent to my server don't show. I'm wondering whether the post request I make with the base64encodedstring alters the encoded string.

Here is what I have done.

```
//Upload picture to server
NSData *imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(showPic.image, 1.0f);
NSLog(@"The size of the image is %i",[imageData length]);
[Base64 initialize];
NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:imageData];

//NSLog(@"This is the encoded string to be uploaded %@",encodedPic);
prefs=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
userid=[prefs stringForKey:@"userid"];

NSLog(@" %@ is the userid to be used to upload the pic",userid);

NSString *poster = @"username=";
poster = [poster stringByAppendingString:userid];
poster = [poster stringByAppendingString:@"&image="];
poster = [poster stringByAppendingString:strEncoded];



NSString *post = poster;
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/server/upload"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: Can you receive the string in server side?

Comment: Then I think there is some problem with your base64 decode at server side. Would you update your question with some server code?

Comment: Actually I found the error. It seems that it's with the dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding it takes out all the + signs from the base64 string changing the whole content that is sent to the server.